# Use of the same jobStep in 2 automatically registered Jobs - Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have two main Spring Batch in my application, that are autoimatically registered with

```
 <bean id="jobRegistrar" class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.AutomaticJobRegistrar">
    <property name="applicationContextFactories">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.ClasspathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean">
            <property name="resources"
                      value="classpath*:/management/*Job_Context.xml"/> <!-- 2 conf files -->
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jobLoader">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.DefaultJobLoader">
            <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Everything was fine, until I decided to use a jobstep, with custom parameter extractors, to be reused in both jobs. I simply added in both job conf files:

```
<beans:import resource="classpath:myJobStepDefinition.xml" />
...
<step id="mySecondaryJob.step">
                <job ref="mySecondaryJob" job-launcher="jobLauncher"
                     job-parameters-extractor="firstJobParametersExtractor"/> <!-- or second -->
</step>
```

The problem is, when I import `myJobStepDefinition.xml` in both conf files, I get an error: job already registered (my guess is that the jobregistrar registers a job per job Definiton in the conf files).

On the countrary, if I get rid of the imports and register the jobstep automatically (by renaming `myJobStepDefinition.xml` into `thirdJob_Context.xml` for example), then I get an error "cannot resolve bean mySecondaryJob".

Is it then impossible to use jobsteps with an AutomaticJobRegistrar ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Each job is registered in the registry, if you load the same configuration twice those jobs will be loaded twice. Hence the error. If you use a `ref` in the `job` tag it is expected that that ref is in the same context (or the parent) else it will fail (it basically is a regular bean `ref` and as such follows the same rules).

Comment: try to change the shared job configuration to an abstract one and use "parent" instead of ref in your specific jobs

Comment: Thanks both of you. I do understand why it fails, but not how to make it work with a clean configuration. Using inheritance works indeed, I hadn't thought about it. But since steps or flows elements are not permitted in abstract job, I need to externalize the setps/flows definitions, and call them when I create the children jobs. Which really makes me think of code duplication. But since it works, I'll mark that as solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael Pralow said, one can use inheritance to solve that problem.

In  this case, the shared job, `mySecondaryJob` must be abstract.

When it has to be used (as step of another job), a non-abstract child job must be created. Watch out, if you want to share flows or steps, you have to externalize the definition of these flows / steps, since it cannot be used within an abstract job (but listeners can). In the following example, I took the simple case where my job has only one step.

```
<job id="myFirstChildJob" parent="mySecondaryJob" abstract="false"> <!-- abstract is false by default -->
    <step id="myFirstChildStep" parent="myAbstractSharedStep"/>
</job>
```